# erlang parallel server error?

Tags: erlang, client-server

I decided to modify the code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807073/erlang-client-server-error) by changing the server to a parallel one (as mentioned in the book) and it doesn't work properly. The following code is supposed to be presto-chango according to the book "Programming Erlang" but I get an error on line 17. Here is the parallel server code (the completed parallel server is on the bottom, this is just the change to the old server code on the last thread),

```
startp() ->
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(4042, [binary, {packet, 0},  
                     {reuseaddr, true},
                     {active, true}]),                       
                     spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Listen) end).

par_connect(Listen) ->      
        {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
        spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Listen) end),
        loop(Socket).
```

and this is the error,

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 12-Feb-2013::23:05:13 ===
Error in process <0.35.0> with exit value: {{badmatch,{error,einval}},[{ps1,loop,1,[{file,"ps1.erl"},{line,17}]}]}
```

The following is the parallel server code, I'm thinking that something is wrong with the argument on line 14 for the call loop(Socket). Maybe its something else, I dunno?

```
-module(ps1).
-compile(export_all).
-import(lists, [reverse/1]).

startp() ->
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(4042, [binary, {packet, 0},  
                     {reuseaddr, true},
                     {active, true}]),                       
                     spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Listen) end).

par_connect(Listen) ->      
        {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
        spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Listen) end),
        loop(Socket).

loop(Listen) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    receive
    {tcp, Socket, Bin} ->
        io:format("Server received binary = ~p~n",[Bin]),
        Str = binary_to_term(Bin), 
        io:format("Server (unpacked)  ~p~n",[Str]),
        Reply = string:to_upper(Str),  
        io:format("Server replying = ~p~n",[Reply]),
        gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary(Reply)),  
        loop(Listen);
    {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
        io:format("Server socket closed~n")
    end.
```

next is the client code which also ends up dieing waiting for a reply

```
c1:nano("list_to_tuple([2+3*4,10+20])").
nano got not answer to "list_to_tuple([2+3*4,10+20])"
{error,timeout}

-module(c1).
-compile(export_all).
-import(lists, [reverse/1]).

%old port 2345
nano(Str) ->
    {ok, Socket} = 
    gen_tcp:connect("localhost", 4042,
            [binary, {packet, 0}]),
    ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary(Str)),
    R = receive
        {tcp,Socket,Bin} ->
            io:format("Client received binary = ~p~n",[Bin]),
            Val = binary_to_term(Bin),
            io:format("Client result = ~p~n",[Val]),
            {ok,Val}
        after 5000 ->
            io:format("nano got no answer to ~p~n",[Str]),
            {error,timeout}
    end,
%   gen_tcp:close(Socket),
    R.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error description you get is a bit strange, according to the documentation:

> einval
>
> ```
> Attempt to delete the current directory. On some platforms, eacces is returned instead.
> ```

I must say that it does not help a lot.

Anyway, you don't need to recall `{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen)` in the loop, while it was already done in `par_connect(Listen)`. but in this case, the argument of the loop will be Socket rather than Listen. You made the correction in per_connect but not in loop (It is the reason of the error you got).

Doing this the first server is spawn, it initializes the connection with gen_tcp:listen, and waits for a connection with gen_tcp:accept. As soon as a connection is established, a new process is launched, waiting on accept, and the loop is called in the current process, with the connection port as parameter.

Now you should write a client smarter than I propose, which can loop for a while using the same open connection :o)

```
-module(socket_examples).
-compile(export_all).

nano_client_eval(Str) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect("localhost", 2345,[binary, {packet, 0}]),
    nano_client_eval(Str,10,Socket).

nano_client_eval(_,0,Socket) ->
    gen_tcp:close(Socket);
nano_client_eval(Str,N,Socket) ->
    ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary(Str ++ " loop " ++ integer_to_list(N))),
    receive
        {tcp,Socket,Bin} ->
            io:format("Client received binary = ~p on socket ~p~n",[Bin,Socket]),
            Val = binary_to_term(Bin),
            io:format("Client result = ~p~n",[Val]),
            timer:sleep(1000),
            nano_client_eval(Str,N-1,Socket)
        after 5000 ->
            io:format("nano_client_eval got not answer to ~p~n",[Str]),
            {error,timeout}
    end.

start_nano_server() ->
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(2345, [binary, {packet, 0},{reuseaddr, true},{active, true}]),                       
    spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Listen) end).

par_connect(Listen) ->      
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Listen) end),
    loop(Socket).                    

loop(Socket) ->
    receive
    {tcp, Socket, Bin} ->
        io:format("Server received binary = ~p~n",[Bin]),
        Str = binary_to_term(Bin),  %% (9)
        io:format("Server (unpacked)  ~p~n",[Str]),
%        Reply = lib_misc:string2value(Str),  %% (10)
        Reply = string:to_upper(Str),  %% (10)
        io:format("Server replying = ~p~n",[Reply]),
        gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary(Reply)),  %% (11)
        loop(Socket);
    {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            io:format("Server socket ~p closed by request~n",[Socket])
    after 60000 ->
            gen_tcp:close(Socket),
            io:format("Server socket ~p closed, no more activity~n",[Socket])
    end.
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the commands that you used to test the client and server? thanks...

Comment: I start 3 VM : werl -sname w0 , werl -sname w1 and werl -sname w2. In one VM I start the server: socket_examples:start_nano_server()., and in the other VM I start the clients socket_examples:nano_client_eval("hello from w1"). and socket_examples:nano_client_eval("hello from w2"). One client could be started in the server window, but I prefer tho separate the different printout in different windows.